# how to draw a line at mean value of cross-section and time-series data using Bar Chart

Tags: dataset, charts, code-review, code-request

I have `Dataset`;

```
jexample = {<|"country" -> "Bhutan", "subregion" -> "South Asia", 
"status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 5.`|>, <|"country" -> "Bhutan", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 7.`|>, <|"country" -> "Bhutan", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 11.`|>, <|"country" -> "Bhutan", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 7.`|>, <|"country" -> "Angola", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 3.`|>, <|"country" -> "Angola", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 7.`|>, <|"country" -> "Angola", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 10.`|>, <|"country" -> "Angola", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 5.`|>, <|"country" -> "Bangladesh", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 2.`|>, <|"country" -> "Bangladesh", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 6.`|>, <|"country" -> "Bangladesh", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 7.`|>, <|"country" -> "Bangladesh", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 9.`|>, <|"country" -> "Cambodia", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 6.`|>, <|"country" -> "Cambodia", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 3.`|>, <|"country" -> "Cambodia", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 5.`|>, <|"country" -> "Cambodia", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 6.`|>, <|"country" -> "Nepal", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 7.`|>, <|"country" -> "Nepal", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 9.`|>, <|"country" -> "Nepal", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011.`, 
"data" -> 8.`|>, <|"country" -> "Nepal", 
"subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
"indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015.`, 
"data" -> 5.`|>, <|"country" -> "S. Islands", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", 
"time" -> 2011.`, "data" -> 3.`|>, <|"country" -> "S. Islands", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", 
"time" -> 2015.`, "data" -> 9.`|>, <|"country" -> "S. Islands", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", 
"time" -> 2011.`, "data" -> 4.`|>, <|"country" -> "S. Islands", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", 
"time" -> 2015.`, "data" -> 7.`|>, <|"country" -> "Kiribati", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", 
"time" -> 2011.`, "data" -> 4.`|>, <|"country" -> "Kiribati", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", 
"time" -> 2015.`, "data" -> 5.`|>, <|"country" -> "Kiribati", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", 
"time" -> 2011.`, "data" -> 8.`|>, <|"country" -> "Kiribati", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", 
"time" -> 2015.`, "data" -> 1.`|>, <|"country" -> "Vanuatu", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "ODC", "indicator" -> "GDP", 
"time" -> 2011.`, "data" -> 6.`|>, <|"country" -> "Vanuatu", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "ODC", "indicator" -> "GDP", 
"time" -> 2015.`, "data" -> 6.`|>, <|"country" -> "Vanuatu", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "ODC", "indicator" -> "EVI", 
"time" -> 2011.`, "data" -> 3.`|>, <|"country" -> "Vanuatu", 
"subregion" -> "SIDS", "status" -> "ODC", "indicator" -> "EVI", 
"time" -> 2015.`, "data" -> 3.`|>};

(* Restructure "jexample" to create a new dataset "ds" *)

  (*By @kglr*)
  ClearAll[reOrg, ds, indicatorList, dsgrouped];
  reOrg = Query[GroupBy[{#"time", #"country"} &] /* Values /* KeyUnion, 
  Apply[Join], <|KeyDrop[{"indicator", "data"}]@#, #indicator -> #data|> &]; 
  ds = reOrg@jexample;
  indicatorList = Normal[Query[First /* Keys]@ds][[5 ;;]];
  dsgrouped =ds[GroupBy[#country &], GroupBy[#time &], All, indicatorList];

 ClearAll[barChart, bcQ];
 barChart[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 BarChart[#, opts, ChartLegends -> Automatic, 
 ChartLabels -> Automatic] &;
 bcQ[opts : OptionsPattern[]][var_String, countryslices_: All, 
  timeslices_: All, f_: Identity] := 
  Query[(countryslices /. {All -> Identity, 
  x_List :> KeyTake[x]}) /* (barChart[opts, PlotLabel -> var][
  f[#]] &), timeslices /. x_List :> KeyTake[x], 
  First@*First@*Values@*KeyTake[var]]
 bcQ[opts : OptionsPattern[]][var_List, rest___] := 
 Row[Append[#[[All, 1]], #[[1, -1, 1, 1]]] &@
 Through[(bcQ[opts][#, rest] & /@ var)@#], Spacer[10]] &

ClearAll[timeList, countryList];
timeList = Normal[Query[First /* Keys]@dsgrouped];
countryList = Normal@Keys@dsgrouped;

Manipulate[
 bcQ[
    ImageSize -> 350,
    Joined -> ({Mean@#[[1]], Max@#[[2]]} &),
    ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
    PlotTheme -> "Business",
    AspectRatio -> 1/2.75
    ][Sort@vars, countries, times, gorder]@dsgrouped,
 {{vars, indicatorList[[{1}]], "measures"}, indicatorList, TogglerBar},
 {{countries, countryList[[{1}]], "countries"}, countryList, 
  TogglerBar},
 {{times, timeList, "times"}, timeList, TogglerBar},
 {{gorder, Identity, 
   "grouping order"}, {Identity -> 
    Column[{"country", "time"}, Alignment -> Center], 
   Transpose -> Column[{"time", "country"}, Alignment -> Center]}}
 ]
```

[image]

My purpose is to calculate `Mean` value of `GDP` across countries for the initial year 2011, associated with purple bars across countries, and draw a line on the bar chart. Similarly, I also want to draw a line at the mean value of the final year 2015, associated with the red bars, across the countries. To accomplish this task, I revised the above `Manipulate` as follows:

```
Manipulate[
aveInitial=Max[Normal@Mean[ds[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All,vars][All,First]]];
aveFinal=Max[Normal@Mean[ds[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All,vars][All,Last]]];
aveI = Max[ds[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All, vars][All, First]];
aveF = Max[ds[GroupBy["country"], GroupBy["time"], All, vars][All, Last]];
bcQ[
ImageSize -> 350,
Joined -> ({Mean@#[[1]], Max@#[[2]]} &),
ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
PlotTheme -> "Business",
AspectRatio -> 1/2.75,
Epilog -> {
  {Dashed, Red, 
   Tooltip[Line[{{0, aveInitial}, {0, Max[aveI] + 0.55}}], aveInitial], 
   Text["Average", {-1, aveInitial}, {-3, -1}]}, {Dashed, Blue, 
   Tooltip[Line[{{0, aveFinal}, {0, Max[aveF] + 0.55}}], 
    aveFinal], Text["Average", {-1, aveFinal}, {-3, -2}]}
  }
][Sort@vars, countries, times, gorder]@dsgrouped,
{{vars, indicatorList[[{1}]], "measures"}, indicatorList, TogglerBar},
{{countries, countryList[[{1}]], "countries"}, countryList,TogglerBar},
{{times, timeList, "times"}, timeList, TogglerBar},
{{gorder, Identity, "grouping order"}, {Identity -> 
Column[{"country", "time"}, Alignment -> Center], 
Transpose -> Column[{"time", "country"}, Alignment -> Center]}}
]
```

In the correctly formatted code, I should have two horizontal lines: one for the mean value of the 2011 average across countries and another for the 2015 average across countries. These averages would allow me to compare the average change over time across countries. Of course, when I switch to `time/country` dialogue box, then the two mean values should be calculated for the initial year over the list of countries, as well as over the final year across the list of countries.

However, there is an error in `Epilog->...` and I cannot find out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We modify `bcQ`  (to prevent errors produced by the original `bcQ` for some input combinations) and wrap it with a function that processes rectangles produced by `bcQ` and add lines for means (over selected countries) for each date:

```
ClearAll[barChart, bcQ, rectAssoc, addMeanLines]
rectAssoc[f_] := Association[Join @@
    (Thread[#[[All, -1]] -> Mean@#[[All, -1, 2, -1]]] & /@ 
       Transpose[f@Cases[#, {{__, _Rectangle} ..}, All]])] &;

addMeanLines[f_] := DeleteCases[#, Line[{x_, x_}], All] & @*
   ReplaceAll[g_Graphics :> 
     Module[{y = rectAssoc[f][g]}, g /. {d___, r : Rectangle[a_, b_, c___]} :> 
       {d, FaceForm[Opacity[.6]], r, 
        CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Darker@Darker@Cases[{d}, _?ColorQ, All], 
         AbsoluteThickness[2], Dashed, Line[Thread[{{a[[1]], b[[1]]}, y@r}]]}]];

barChart[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := BarChart[#, opts, 
    ChartLegends -> Automatic, ChartLabels -> Automatic] &;

bcQ[opts : OptionsPattern[]][var : (_String | {_String}), 
  countryslices_: All, timeslices_: All, f_: Identity] := 
 Query[(countryslices /. {All -> Identity, x_List :> KeyTake[x]}) /* 
   KeySort /* (barChart[opts, PlotLabel -> (var /. {x_} :> x)][f @ #] &), 
  timeslices /. x_List :> KeyTake[x], 
  First@*First@*Values@*KeyTake[var]]

bcQ[opts : OptionsPattern[]][var : {_String, __String}, rest___] := 
 Multicolumn[Append[Cases[#, _Graphics, All], FirstCase[#, _SwatchLegend, "", All]] &@
    Through[(bcQ[opts][#, rest] & /@ var)@#], 3, Appearance -> "Horizontal"] &

ClearAll[timeList, countryList];
timeList = Sort @ Normal[Query[First /* Keys] @ dsgrouped];
countryList = Sort @ Normal @ Keys @ dsgrouped;
```

Add `TrackingFunction`s to controls to avoid empty input data sets:

```
Manipulate[addMeanLines[gorder] @
  bcQ[ImageSize -> 350, Joined -> ({Mean@#[[1]], Max@#[[2]]} &), 
     ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Business", 
     AspectRatio -> 1/2.75, ImageSize -> Large][Sort@vars, countries, 
    times, gorder]@dsgrouped, 
 {{vars, indicatorList[[{1}]], "measures"}, indicatorList, TogglerBar, 
  TrackingFunction -> (vars = If[# === {}, indicatorList[[{1}]], Sort@#]; &)}, 
 {{countries, countryList[[{1}]], "countries"}, countryList, TogglerBar, 
  TrackingFunction -> (countries = If[# === {}, countryList[[{1}]], #]; 
     If[Length@# == 1, gorder = Identity]; &)}, 
 {{times, timeList, "times"}, timeList, TogglerBar, 
  TrackingFunction -> (times = If[# === {}, timeList[[{1}]], Sort@#]; 
     If[Length@# == 1, gorder = Transpose]; &)}, 
 {{gorder, Identity, "grouping order"}, 
   {Identity -> Column[{"country", "time"}, Alignment -> Center], 
   Transpose -> Column[{"time", "country"}, Alignment -> Center]}}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Everything works nicely for a dataset with no missing observation. However, when there is a missing observation for a given country, the average value line is not shown for the entire group of countries in the given year. For example, in your first `Barchart` above, if Kiribati has a missing observation in 2011 for the measure `EVI`, then the `code` does not give an average line for the group of three countries in 2011 and turns the bar chart color to RED. For me, it would be sufficient to have the current bar charts if I can avoid the RED color. Thank you very much.